# issue with if else conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the page is open, it automatically set's a timeout to preform a task.
What i want is to change the timing if an event occur. If the user click a button, it changes the time right after the click.

If the user does nothing, the page should auto refresh after a given time, if the user click on "#b1" , the initial timeout should be interrupted and beggin a new one with other time set

I've tried the previous code, but it only executes the last alert .
How can i accomplish this ?

```js
var clicked = 0;
var time = '';

$('#b1').click(function() {
  clicked = 1;
});

if (clicked == 1) {
  time = 10;
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert('clicked');
  }, time);
} else {
  time = 10000;
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert('nothingDone');
  }, time);
}
```

Comment: _"If the user does nothing, the page should auto refresh after a given time"_ What do you mean by "auto refresh"? What is the "given time"?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hda04w4x/

Answer (score 0):

Define a global variable where `setTimeout` is the value, call `clearTimeout()` with variable as parameter if user clicks `#b1` element, then set variable to `setTimeout()` call within event handler

```js
$(function() {

  var clicked = 0;
  var time = '';
  var timer;

  function updateTimer() {
    time = 10;
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      alert('clicked');
    }, time);
  }

  $('#b1').click(function() {
    clicked = 1;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    updateTimer()
  });

  if (clicked == 1) {
    updateTimer()
  } else {
    time = 10000;
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      alert('nothingDone');
    }, time);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="b1">click</div>
```

Comment: yep.. that's it ... it required a few more lines than i even think of 
Thanks